# Почему не выводит по убыванию sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
select DATE_FORMAT( time_reports.date, '%W'), group_concat(employees.name, ' (', x.total_hours, ' hours)' SEPARATOR  ', '  LIMIT 3)  
  from employees
  inner join time_reports on employees.id=time_reports.employee_id
  inner join 
    (
      select employee_id, round(hours,2) as total_hours 
        from time_reports group by employee_id
         ORDER BY total_hours DESC
       )x on x.employee_id=time_reports.employee_id
  group by time_reports.date
```

x.total_hours должно выводиться 3 максимальных значения. Limit 3 работает, а вот как сделать ORDER BY total_hours DESC что бы работало ( я поставил во второй SELECT но эффекта ноль), если ставить в самом конце, то срабатывает тогда не только на total_hours но и на DATE_FORMAT, а нужно только на total_hours

Comment: Очень интересно... А у вас какой MySQL ? я не вижу в документации на group_concat упоминание лимита. И у меня limit внутри group concat действительно не работает (на 5 версии). Зато в документации и по факту внутри group_concat можно задавать собственный order by, который как раз упорядочивает элементы внутри списка

Comment: И кстати внутренний запрос у вас сам по себе странный. round(hours,2) при использовании group by возьмет часы только из одной, причем первой попавшейся, записи для данного employee_id. Это по названию на total как то не тянет, мне кажется там sum() пропущен